# Ideal way to set up a JMS connection so it auto reconnects

Tags: java, jms, messenger

I'm currently programming a messenger service for durable subscriptions (it might end up being non durable we are still discussing that) and I was looking for some suggestions on how to handle a scenario where our server goes temporarily down for whatever reason and we need to resubscribe to the topic automatically. Here is sample code of how it connects:

```
public void DurableChatter(String broker, String username, String password)
{
    javax.jms.MessageProducer publisher = null;
    javax.jms.MessageConsumer subscriber = null;
    javax.jms.Topic topic = null;

    //Create a connection:
    try{
        javax.jms.ConnectionFactory factory;
        factory = (new progress.message.jclient.ConnectionFactory (broker));
        connection = factory.createConnection (username, password);

        //Durable Subscriptions are indexed by username, clientID and subscription name
        //It is a good proactice to set the clientID:
        connection.setClientID(CLIENT_ID);
        pubSession = connection.createSession(false,javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        subSession = connection.createSession(false,javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }
    catch (javax.jms.JMSException jmse){
        System.err.println ("Error: Cannot connect to Broker - " + broker);
        jmse.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    //Create Publisher and Durable Subscriber:
    try{

        topic = pubSession.createTopic(APP_TOPIC);
        subscriber = subSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "SampleSubscription");
        subscriber.setMessageListener(this);
        publisher = pubSession.createProducer(topic);
        connection.start();
    }
    catch (javax.jms.JMSException jmse){
        System.out.println("Error: connection not started.");
        jmse.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    //Wait for user input

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Enter text to send as message and press enter.");
        java.io.BufferedReader stdin =
            new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true)
        {
            String s = stdin.readLine();

            if(s == null){
                exit();
            }
            else if (s.length()>0)
            {
                try
                {
                    javax.jms.TextMessage msg = pubSession.createTextMessage();
                    msg.setText(username + ": " + s);
                    //Publish the message persistantly:
                    publisher.send(
                        msg,                               //message
                        javax.jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, //publish persistantly
                        javax.jms.Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY,//priority
                        MESSAGE_LIFESPAN);                 //Time to Live
                }
                catch (javax.jms.JMSException jmse){
                    System.err.println("Error publishing message:" + jmse.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how fast do you need failure detection to be?
set up your protocol so that it guarantees every client is sent a message at least once a minute (you'll need to add some new "fluff" keepalive message to your communication protocol) - any client not receiving a keepalive message can safely assume the server is down and begin reconnecting.

ideally this sort of thing is best done with UDP broadcast and not JMS (for the overhead), but i assume if you have UDP broadcast as an option you'd use jgroups to do you cluster detecion/failover/rejoin for you.

Comment: It doesn't have to be instant if that's what you are asking. Is there anyway this can be done with a try/catch block?

Comment: only if the underlying connection throws some sort of exception when its severed. i couldnt tell you without trying.

Answer (score 3):

You should make your client [`implement javax.jmsExceptionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html).

This will allow your client to instantly receive a callback from the JMS API when the connection is lost, even if your application is not tying to publish anything at the moment.

After creating the `Connection`, connecting and starting it, call `connection.setExceptionListener(myListener)`. See also the Javadoc for [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#setExceptionListener-javax.jms.ExceptionListener-).